# Id of entity is different after hibernate save from oracle database with sequence autogeneration id

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Entity with id autogenerated from oracle trigger sequence.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REPORT", schema = "WEBPORTAL")
public class Report {
    private Integer id;
....


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="report_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="report_sequence", sequenceName = "report_id_seq")
    @Column(name="REPORT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
....
}
```

Service

```
@Service("reportService")
public class ReportServiceImpl implements ReportService {
....

    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public void saveOrUpdate(Report report) {
        reportDAO.saveOrUpdate(report);
    }
}
```

DAO

```
@Repository
public class ReportDAOImpl implements ReportDAO {
....

    @Override
    public Report save(Report report) {
        try {
           Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
           session.save(report);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           logger.error("error", e);
        }
        return report;
    }
}
```

**And When I call service's saveOrUpdate and then try to reach id of entity I get different value than persisted in database.** Values on database with autogeneration all is ok. Any suggestions?

```
reportService.saveOrUpdate(report);
System.out.println(report.getId());
```

prints: 4150
but saved id in database is: 84

**NOTE:** My purpose to get Id comes from that I wanted to save childs with cascade. But foreign key on child was different in database(the values of id that I get with getId()).

And Id generated in database is incremented by 2. EX: 80, 82, 84.

**UPDATE:**

Oracle trigger for sequence generation

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER REPORT_ID_TRIG    
BEFORE INSERT ON WEBPORTAL.REPORT  
FOR EACH ROW   
BEGIN   
    SELECT report_id_seq.NEXTVAL  
    INTO :new.report_id  
    FROM dual;  
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ANSWER:** Trigger should check if id is null

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER REPORT_ID_TRIG
BEFORE INSERT ON WEBPORTAL.REPORT
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.report_id is null)
BEGIN 
    SELECT report_id_seq.NEXTVAL
    INTO :new.report_id
    FROM dual;
END;
```

**DESCRIPTION:**
@GeneratedValue is not just a sequence generator. It's bit of HiLo algorithm.When it first requests id from database it multiplies it with 50(it can differ) and next 50 new entities will be given ids consequently, and than next request to database. This is to decrease request to database.
 The numbers that I get from java was right numbers that should be saved on report.

Without id null value check Hibernate firstly requested for id from database and sequence.nextval called. When hibernate was persisting it(completing transaction) the database called sequence.next second time and set that value to database. So on ReportDetails there was true id value of report and on the Report id it was id set from database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that two separate mechanisms are in place to generate the key:

- one at Hibernate level which is to call a sequence and use the value to populate an Id column and send it to the database as the insert key
- and another mechanism at the database that Hibernate does not know about: the column is incremented via a trigger.

Hibernate thinks that the insert was made with the value of the sequence, but in the database something else occurred. The simplest solution would probably be to remove the trigger mechanism, and let Hibernate populate the key based on the sequence only.

**Another Solution:**
check your trigger definition that should be in this format
(`WHEN (new.report_id is null)` ) is important.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_NAME
   BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE_NAME
   FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN (new.id is null)
     BEGIN 
       SELECT SEQUENCE_NAME.NEXTVAL
       INTO :new.id
       FROM dual;
     END
```