# Returned entity ID is different from the actual data saved in the database

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA. When I'm inspecting the Entity returned by the save(Entity) method, it is different from the actual ID saved in the database. I'm using Oracle and my Entity ID config is using sequence from Oracle db.

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "SEQ_NAME")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_NAME", sequenceName = "SEQ_1", allocationSize = 1)
private BigDecimal id;
```

Example scenario:

1. Insert record1 using save(record1);
2. Inspected record1 to have ID = 1001
3. Checked the db and the ID is 1002.

All other data are OK except the ID.

EDIT:

I remove all other logic in the code and leave just the saving part to isolate the issue.

Comment: If you debugged insertion, the behavior is exoected. It triggers sequence creation and crests a new one later while inserting. Just leave it as is, the sequence would be fine.

Comment: but I'm using the returned ID and will use that to reference to that record later on. so I need it to be precise.How can I make sure to get the inserted ID instead?

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67194370/6498792) post that describe the problem completly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that there's a db trigger that calls the SEQ1.nextVal every time a record is getting inserted. Dropping the trigger and altering the table to have DEFAULT SEQ1.nextVal solves my problem.